# call a async function inside useEffect hook but get error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have a function to get access token from local storage, if found then show user the main screen otherwise, show login screen. The function is defined in a js file named `utils.js`. Here is the function:

```
const tryLocalSignin = (dispatch) => async () => {
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
  if (token) {
    console.log("Got token from AsyncStorage!");
    dispatch(signInFulfilled(token));
    navigate("mainFlow");
  } else {
    console.log("No token got from AsyncStorage...");
    navigate("loginFlow");
  }
};
```

In my SigninScreen.js, I would like to first run the above function so that user could be directly navigate to the main screen if token is found. Here is part of my SigninScreen.js

```
const SigninScreen = ({ token, error, dispatch }) => {
  // use the useEffect hook to run the tryLocalSignin() once.
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(utils.tryLocalSignin());
  }, []);

  return (<View>...</View>)
  ...
  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SigninScreen). // redux way to connect to storage
```

When I launch the Signin screen, I can see from the log that the code successfully got token from storage, but there is also an error:

```
Try local signin
Got token from AsyncStorage!

[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: dispatch is not a function. (In 'dispatch((0, _authActions.signInFulfilled)(token))', 'dispatch' is undefined)]
* src/utils.js:63:13 in <anonymous>
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:274:30 in invoke
```

Why I get this error? How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you use react-redux hooks like this :

```
import React,{useEffect} from "react"
import {useSelector,useDispatch} from "react-redux"
import utils from "./utils"

    const SigninScreen = () => {
     const {token,error} = useSelector(state=>state)
     const dispatch = useDispatch()
      useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(utils.tryLocalSignin());
      }, []);

      return (<View>...</View>)
      ...
      export default SigninScreen
```

and i you are using async actions you need to use redux async middleware to enable this install `redux-thunk`:

`npm i redux-thunk`

then use in your store :

```
import thunk from redux-thunk 
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like this

const [value, setDispatch] = useState(false);

and then use setDispatch(true) in your useEffect()